# Multiple media queries in css not working

Tags: html, css

I have multiple queries in my stylesheet where the code`@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) { }` works perfectly fine but under it I have `@media screen and (min-device-width : 176px) (max-device-width : 360px) {}` does not work.

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) { 
body {background: red; } }


@media screen and (min-device-width : 176px) (max-device-width : 360px) {
body {background: green; } }
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean exactly? What does not apply at which screen resolutions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're missing the `AND` between `(min-device-width : 176px) (max-device-width : 360px).`

```
@media screen and (min-device-width : 176px) and  (max-device-width : 360px) {
    body {background: green; } 
}
```

The other issues here is you are using `min-device-width.`(referring to the resolution of the device vs browser width)  which is what @NoobEditor is saying below.

Are you doing that on purpose?  If not you should be using `min-width` && `max-width`

---

```
@media screen and (min-width : 176px) and  (max-width : 360px) {
    body {background: green; } 
}
```

Answer (score 10):

[**check this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hDQAP/1/), change the browser width to see the the media query in action

```
@media screen and (max-width : 1500px) {
    body {
        background: #000;
        border-top: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
    body {
        background: #fff;
        border-top: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
    }
}
```

This fiddle works fine, but **if you change the order of the media queries** it wont work...try it for yourself!

CSS always selects the last style that was declared if multiple style are found for an attrib.

**for e.g :**

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    background: black;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background: white;
  }
}
```

for `765px` ( *since both m.q cover this width* ) color selected would be `white`

Answer (score 7):

For multiple `width` for same style, use `,`:

```
@media (max-width: 360px), (max-width: 768px) {

    /* style goes here */

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code sample. I was missing that I didn't have to repeat @media after the comma.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution. You have to make 2 CSS files, in the first code the first media query and in the second write yout second media query code. I know it is an elegant way to do it but it works.